# Getting the occurrences of words in a file and storing them with the count of their occurences

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to read the occurrences of each word in a file and store it in a hashmap with it's number of occurences. This is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {
            HashMap<String, Integer> map = sortingFromAFile("file.txt");
            printMap(map);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static HashMap sortingFromAFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {

        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        Integer count = 1;

        File file = new File(fileName);

        Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(file);
            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                if (map.containsKey(line)){
                    map.put(line, count++);
                }
                map.put(line, count);

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return map;
    }

    public static void printMap(HashMap map){
        Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + ":" + pairs.getValue()  );
        }
    }
```

The program just runs to print out the text in the file. What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: The scanner class tokenizes each word, thus nextLine( )means the next string delimited by a white space.

Comment: Nope, `nextLine()` advances the cursor to the next line. You probably mean `next()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the lines and then use the map, otherwise you are just reading and adding lines, and if the lines are not the same you will get 1 occurrence of each line.

```
 String [] words= line.split("[\\W]");
```

Comment: If my understanding is right, the scanner class tokenizes each word, thus nextLine( )means the next string delimited by a white space.

Comment: print line and let me know what does it have, it have been a long time without using Java, but it does not seem to work as you are trying.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html here it is clearly mentioned nextLine() advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.

Answer (score 0):

You have a counting bug as well as incorrect use of `Scanner` class, change:

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if (map.containsKey(line)){
        map.put(line, count++);
    }
    map.put(line, count);

}
```

to:

```
while(sc.hasNext()){
    String word = sc.next();
    if (map.containsKey(word)){
        map.put(word, map.get(word)+1);
    }
    else {
        map.put(word, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: ` Integer present=map.get(word);
    if (present!=null){
        present=present+1;
    }
    else {
        map.put(word, 1);
    }` is bit quicker for that update inside loop

Comment: @user1289300 it's not quicker: don't forget that all the actions performed on a Map have runtime of `O(1)` ;)

Comment: besides above would not work because Integer is immutable, I obviously meant mutable Integer wrapper above, you’re right its o(1) and difference though  exists is negligible

Comment: @user1289300 int immutability has nothing to do with this solution. We're not "changing" an integer, what we do is update a key stored in a map to have a new value.

Comment: well not exactly, you update value, for the key and the value is  in my case  mutable integer wrapper so you can update value object without updating value for the key, i meant my first comment would not work not your solution

Comment: @user1289300 yes you can do that too (update `Integer`), but I still don't understand why did you come to a conclusion that this solution wouldn't work?

Comment: my first comment would not work, not your solution, sorry for confusion, i tried to change immutable Integer object which would not affect the value in the map

Answer (score 0):

i have written this piece of code that is applicable to any type of String you enter it returns the repetitive word  with its length,maybe this can be any helpful to you,you can easily change it for reading from file according to your needs,you can use hashmap to store the occurene of repeative words in each line and then compare it with the match words from the last line and so on.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

/**
 * @author ArslanAppstellation
 *
 */

```
public class RedundancyDetector {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String userinput = "";
    while (true) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        userinput = scanner.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s", "");
        if (userinput.contains("letsquit")) {
            break;
        }

        System.out.println(redudantString(userinput));
    }

}

public static String redudantString(String longStringOfCharacters) {

    // form the N Parts
    int N = longStringOfCharacters.length();
    String[] stringParts = new String[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        stringParts[i] = longStringOfCharacters.substring(i, N);
    }
    // sort them
    Arrays.sort(stringParts);

     String longest = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
        String iteratedLongest = matchWords(stringParts[i],
                stringParts[i + 1]);
        if (iteratedLongest.length() > longest.length())
            longest = iteratedLongest;
    }
    System.out.println(longest.length());
    return longest;
}

public static String matchWords(String ithElement, String ithplus1Element) {
    int length = Math.min(ithElement.length(), ithplus1Element.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (ithElement.charAt(i) != ithplus1Element.charAt(i))
            return ithElement.substring(0, i);
    }
    return ithElement.substring(0, length);
} }
```